# How to send a byte[] with buffer to a server?

Tags: android, arrays, sockets, buffer

I try to send a byte[] with an ssl socket and a buffer to my server, but doesn't succeed the buffer.
I search a lot, and see that some topics look like mine, but I try their code (adapting to my case), but never succeed. Your help would be great, thanks.

EDIT client side (android):

```
byte[] bytes = null;

    Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.test);
    ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    bmp.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, stream);
    bytes = stream.toByteArray();
    File file = new File(String.valueOf(bytes));
    ImageView mImageView = findViewById(R.id.imageView2);

    Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getApplicationContext().getResources(),
            R.drawable.test);
    mImageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);

    if (socketConnect()) {
        try {
            Log.d("MainActivity", "Before OutputStream");
            OutputStream os = sock.getOutputStream();
            os.write(bytes);

            os.flush();
            os.close();
            //in.close();
            sock.close();
            Log.d("MainActivity", "End");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    else {
        Log.e("MainActivity", "Erreur");
    }
```

Server side (python):

```
import socket
import sys
import ssl


sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
sock.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
sock.bind(("",9999))

sock.listen(10)

i=1

while True:
    (clientsocket, (ip, port)) = sock.accept()
    connstream = ssl.wrap_socket(clientsocket,
                                 server_side = True,
                                 certfile = "server.crt",
                                 keyfile = "server.key")
    f = open('file_'+str(i)+".png",'wb') #open in binary
    i=i+1
    print(i)
    l = 1
    l = connstream.read(1024)
    while (l):
        print("toto")
        f.write(l)
        l = connstream.read(1024)
    f.close()

    connstream.close()

sock.close()
```

When I run my code it seem that my FileInputStream doesn't work

Thank for your help

EDIT :

Logcat :

```
05-25 15:41:45.993 16257-16257/? I/zygote: Not late-enabling -Xcheck:jni (already on)
05-25 15:41:46.020 16257-16257/? W/zygote: Unexpected CPU variant for X86 using defaults: x86
05-25 15:41:46.477 16257-16257/com.youstiti.simon.testenvoiwithbuffer 
I/InstantRun: starting instant run server: is main process
05-25 15:41:46.952 16257-16257/com.youstiti.simon.testenvoiwithbuffer 
E/MainActivity: debut connexion socket
Choix bks version
05-25 15:41:46.953 16257-16257/com.youstiti.simon.testenvoiwithbuffer 
E/MainActivity: Bks recup
05-25 15:41:46.978 16257-16257/com.youstiti.simon.testenvoiwithbuffer 
E/MainActivity: Connexion socket
05-25 15:41:46.978 16257-16257/com.youstiti.simon.testenvoiwithbuffer 
D/MainActivity: Before OutputStream
05-25 15:41:47.002 16257-16257/com.youstiti.simon.testenvoiwithbuffer 
D/MainActivity: Before FileInputStream
05-25 15:41:47.002 16257-16257/com.youstiti.simon.testenvoiwithbuffer 
W/System.err: java.io.FileNotFoundException: [B@838f46d (No such file or directory)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.open0(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.open(FileInputStream.java:200)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:150)
    at com.youstiti.simon.testenvoiwithbuffer.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:115)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6975)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1213)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2770)
05-25 15:41:47.003 16257-16257/com.youstiti.simon.testenvoiwithbuffer 
W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2892)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1593)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:105)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6541)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:240)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:767)
05-25 15:41:47.021 16257-16282/com.youstiti.simon.testenvoiwithbuffer 
D/OpenGLRenderer: HWUI GL Pipeline
05-25 15:41:47.047 16257-16282/com.youstiti.simon.testenvoiwithbuffer 
I/OpenGLRenderer: Initialized EGL, version 1.4
05-25 15:41:47.047 16257-16282/com.youstiti.simon.testenvoiwithbuffer 
D/OpenGLRenderer: Swap behavior 1
05-25 15:41:47.047 16257-16282/com.youstiti.simon.testenvoiwithbuffer 
W/OpenGLRenderer: Failed to choose config with 
EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR_PRESERVED, retrying without...
05-25 15:41:47.047 16257-16282/com.youstiti.simon.testenvoiwithbuffer 
D/OpenGLRenderer: Swap behavior 0
05-25 15:41:47.052 16257-16282/com.youstiti.simon.testenvoiwithbuffer 
D/EGL_emulation: eglCreateContext: 0xa5a31e60: maj 2 min 0 rcv 2
05-25 15:41:47.061 16257-16282/com.youstiti.simon.testenvoiwithbuffer 
D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0xa5a31e60: ver 2 0 (tinfo 0x99aa9d20)
05-25 15:41:47.101 16257-16282/com.youstiti.simon.testenvoiwithbuffer 
D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0xa5a31e60: ver 2 0 (tinfo 0x99aa9d20)
```

EDIT LOGCAT OUTOFMEMORY :

```
--------- beginning of crash
05-25 16:24:02.845 14571-14571/com.youstiti.simon.youstititest E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.youstiti.simon.youstititest, PID: 14571
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Failed to allocate a 509239740 byte allocation with 33554432 free bytes and 445MB until OOM
    at java.lang.AbstractStringBuilder.<init>(AbstractStringBuilder.java:83)
    at java.lang.StringBuilder.<init>(StringBuilder.java:67)
    at java.util.Arrays.toString(Arrays.java:2062)
    at com.youstiti.simon.youstititest.activity.GalleryActivity$Upload.doInBackground(GalleryActivity.java:145)
    at com.youstiti.simon.youstititest.activity.GalleryActivity$Upload.<init>(GalleryActivity.java:94)
    at com.youstiti.simon.youstititest.activity.GalleryActivity.onActivityResult(GalleryActivity.java:84)
    at android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult(Activity.java:6463)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:3738)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:3785)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1400(ActivityThread.java:157)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1405)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5525)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:730)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:620)
```

Comment: Please provide the stack trace, also put some log everywhere to see what happen

Comment: `File file = new File(String.valueOf(bytes));` That is nonsense. You have bytes in memory. You do not need the File class.

Comment: Yes but FileInputStream need a file, so I supposed that would work

Comment: Further you want to upload a resource R.drawable.test wich is a file in drawables. You do not need to convert to bitmap and all other extra things. You could just directly open an InputStream for it and then use it like you do for your impossible FileInputStream now.

Answer (score 0):

> File file = new File(String.valueOf(bytes));

That is nonsense. You have bytes in memory. You do not need the File class

> FileInputStream in = new FileInputStream(bytes);

That is nonsense too. You do not need a FileInputStream and second you cannot use it for bytes in this way. Does that compile? Really?

You can do away with that all. The only thing you need is:

```
os.write(bytes);
```

Comment: So no buffer ? why ?

Comment: byte[] bytes is your buffer that contains all.

Comment: Yes but I want to send byte[] bytes by pack of 1024, cause of the error out of memory.

Comment: Well you have the whole image in memory already. In bytes[]. Then please tell which statement exactly causes the out of memory. Post the stacktrace. And your updated code.

Comment: When I try to send a video, the application crash, when I just want to send one image that work fine, when I multiple the number of image, the application crash.

Comment: You cannot even send one image from resources now with your code. And certainly not a video. So where are you talking about? Makes no sense.

Comment: That not exactly the same code as before, here I take a picture or a video from the gallery and I send it to the server. One image work but that all

Comment: Well does the code work now for that file from resources? Is indeed os.write(bytes); sufficient? If so than you should first tell us if it works for you now. Dont talk about other code yet and other problems.

Comment: Well then your problem is solved. If you have other code and other problems then make a new post.

Comment: Yes but I want it with a buffer